# Split and join in C# using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have the below string array.

```
 string[] sentence = new string[] { "The quick brown", "fox jumps over", "the lazy dog." };
```

**I want to split it with " " and rejoin with #.**
This is for learning linq in c#. I know i can easily manage this with replace and other built in features. But i am trying in this way.

```
 var sentenceresult = sentence.Select(c => c.Split(' '))
```

but how to apply "#" for each item?

Comment: So what is the expected output? You said split by `""` but in your code you are spliting by `' '`.

Comment: Is Linq really appropriate here?

Comment: @SteveWellens . No ..absolutely not. Its just for educational purpose.

Comment: @RahulSingh. Yes you are right. I updated the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with `String.Join`.

This should give you the expected output:-

```
string[] result = sentence.Select(x => String.Join("#", x.Split(' ')))
                          .ToArray();
```

[Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zyE2yO)

**Update:**

`Enumerable.Select` projects each item from your array `sentence`. So when you say `Select(x =>` x will iterate through your array and will hold follwoing values in each iteration:-

```
"The quick brown"
"fox jumps over"
"the lazy dog."
```

Now, consider just the first sentence. `String.Join` method:

> Concatenates all the elements of a string array, using the specified
>   separator between each element.

So when we say `x.Split(' ')` it will actually split `"The quick brown"` (remember we are considering the first sentence here) and return a string array which is joined with `#`. Similarly for other sentence it will join the sentence.

Comment: Why the `x.Select(z => z)`? Shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @BradfordDillon - You are correct, since it is string array it is not required. Thanks.

Comment: @rahul Singh..Thats great. it works perfect. I have one more doubt.  sentence.Select(x => x.Split(' '))
                          .Select(x => String.Join("#", x))
                          .ToArray(); works. But if i replace x in the second select statement with another variable it not works.    sentence.Select(x => x.Split(' '))
                          .Select(x => String.Join("#", c))
                          .ToArray();  As per my understatnding first processed result will be available in the second select statement and the variable name is not important here. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Ammu - Check my update for explanation and let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: Your updated query is clear. But still would like to know if i am using multiple select statement do i need to use the same variable ? i.e can i try like this?  sentence.Select(x => x.Split(' ')) .Select(x => String.Join("#", c)) .ToArray();

Comment: @Ammu - Same variable as in you mean `x`? absolutely because they are methods and each `x` acts like a local variable inside each method. But please note each method (`Select`) iterates over every item.

Comment: If each x scope is only to that method, why sentence.Select(x => x.Split(' ')) .Select(x => String.Join("#", c)) .ToArray(); is not working?

Comment: @Ammu - Cz you are using `c` in your last `Select` method so your code won't even compile. `sentence.Select(x => x.Split(' ')).Select(x => String.Join("#", x)).ToArray();` will give you the expected output.

Answer (score 2):

Using what you have `var sentenceresult = sentence.Select(c => c.Split(' '))` this will give you an enumerable of string arrays, ie. `IEnumerable<string[]>` where each entry in the enumerable is a string array of words from each substring. This is somewhat clunky to work with, unless you're really sure it's what you want.

You probably want to use `SelectMany`:

```
var sentenceresult = sentence.SelectMany(c => c.Split(' '));
```

This will give you a single collection of `string` objects, where each string is a single word from the individual  which is equivalent to this:

```
var sentenceresult = new [] { "The", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog." };
```

Then you can use `string.Join(sentenceresult)` to get the following result:

```
The#quick#brown#fox#jumps#over#the#lazy#dog.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try a one-line solution:

```
string[] res = sentence.Select(str => String.Join("#", str.Split())).ToArray();
```

Or if you want one string:

```
string res2 = String.Join("#", sentence.SelectMany(str => str.Split()));
```